# Merge two sorted list using orient object programming

Tags: python

I am merge sorted list, I am using the following function:

```
def mergeTwoLists(list1,list2):
    if len(list1)==0:
        return list2
    elif len(list2)==0:
        return list1
    elif list1[0]<=list2[0]:
        return [list1[0]]+mergeTwoLists(list1[1:],list2)
    elif list2[0]<list1[0]:
        return [list2[0]]+mergeTwoLists(list1,list2[1:])

mergeTwoLists([3,5,4],[1,3])
```

However, I notice there is a answer that uses class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=1, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists1(self, l1, l2):
        if l1 is None:
            return l2
        elif l2 is None:
            return l1
        elif l1.val < l2.val:
            l1.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
            return l1
        else:
            l2.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
            return l2
```

How can I call the second function? What is the benefit of using it?

Comment: The version you wrote operates on arrays, or vectors (which Python calls "lists").  The class version operates on genuine linked lists.  Although the recursion is unnecessary in both cases, and would not be used by efficient implementations, the linked list version will be far more efficient than the first version, since it does not require copying arrays on each recursive call.  The first version has time complexity O(n^2), which the second is O(n).  The problem with the first version is `list1[1:]` and `list2[1:]`, which perform array copies.  Avoid that.

Comment: I find this article, can be useful for you: https://www.educba.com/functional-programming-vs-oop/

Comment: At the most fundamental level, you probably want to understand the differences (and pros and cons) between arrays vs. linked lists.